# Connection between almost sure convergence and lim sup and lim inf

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I noticed other similar questions about this, but I'm going in circles. Am I correct that the following are equivalent ways of showing $X_n$ a sequence of random variables converges almost surely to zero? Assume $X_n$ greater than or equal to $0$ for all $n$ for ease of notation, and limsup's and liminf's are taken as n goes to infinity.

1. Show that $P(\limsup \{X_n > \epsilon\}) = 0$
2. Show that $P(\liminf {X_n < \epsilon}) = 1$, this being the complement of (1), correct?

Is it correct to interpret this as: if the limit of $X_n$ exists, say $0$, then 
$$\liminf X_n = \limsup X_n = \lim X_n = 0$$ 
so statements (1) and (2) above are really just saying that, for sufficiently large $n$, the probability of $X_n$ exceeding arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ is zero, or, equivalently, that the probability of $X_n$ being less than or equal to $\epsilon$ is one. But this sounds exactly like the definition of convergence in probability, but proving this will not guarantee almost sure convergence, hence, my issue.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. "But this sounds exactly like the definition of convergence in probability, but proving this will not guarantee almost sure convergence, hence, my issue."  Are you saying that proving convergence will not guarantee almost sure convergence?

Comment: I mean that proving convergence in probability does not imply convergence almost surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement of $\limsup \{X_n > \epsilon\}$ is $\liminf \{X_n \leqslant \epsilon\}$, which contains $\{\limsup X_n\lt\epsilon\}$ and is included in $\{\limsup X_n\leqslant\epsilon\}$.
Equivalently, 
$$
\{\limsup X_n \gt \epsilon\}\subseteq\limsup \{X_n > \epsilon\}\subseteq\{\limsup X_n \geqslant \epsilon\}.
$$
An example to show that the first inclusion may be strict is $\{\forall n,X_n=\epsilon+1/n\}$. An example to show that the second inclusion may be strict is $\{\forall n,X_n=\epsilon-1/n\}$.

Yes these are rather subtle interplays between the limsup of sets and the limsup of random variables, and between strict and large inequalities.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Do you happen to have an online reference from which I can study more such subtleties? The prob. books I have deal with this topic very briefly.

Comment: Sorry, nothing comes to mind at the moment--except to think hard about the definitions.

Comment: @Did : In $\limsup\{X_n>\epsilon\}$, the subtlety does not arise from the fact that $\mathbb N$ is countable ?

Comment: @the-owner Well, the notion of limsup of a finite family does not seem a very promising one, does it?

Comment: @Did : Do you mean that $n$ tend to $+\infty$($\notin \mathbb N$) in the version of $\limsup$ for sets ?

Comment: @the-owner Sorry but I am not following. Either you know the definition of limsup for sets (and for random variables) or you don't. If you don't, please go and check it. If you do, what is your point?

Comment: @Did I said that because $\limsup A_n$ is a countable intersection and union ? (... mean I can  at least find a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and the $A_n$) and I have thought that it was one of the key points to understand these sets inequalities.

Comment: @the-owner Each $A_n$ can be uncoutably infinite, whether it is or is not is completely beside the point. Please refer to a solid definition of limsup. (If you have a substantial question about a notion, the way to go is to ask a question about it, not to troll a three years old thread.)

Comment: @the-owner *Stop trolling this thread and go check your definitions*. Thanks in advance. No more comments here from me on this.